# Why is my KendoUI Grid not showing my data, have I configured Automapper incorrectly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, kendo-ui, automapper

I am having a problem with my KendoUI grid, it's not showing data that is returned.  I am using a repository pattern and automapper to eleviate some of the crunt work from using viewmodels.

In a nutshell, my controller asks the repository for all records with a specific Id and maps them to a view model to avoid circular references. The collection is stored in a variable and passed as json to the grid in the view.

The problem is that despite data being returned (observable with a break point) the grid never shows anything and I can't figure out why.

The below code shows how I have set everything up:

**Controller**

```
namespace DataAccessTest.Controllers
{
    public class GridController : Controller
    {
        private IFixturesRepository fixtureRepository;

        public GridController()
        {
            this.fixtureRepository= new FixturesRepository(new CoreEntities());
        }

        // GET: Grid
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        // Id paramter is fed from a grid in a different view.
        public ActionResult fixtures([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int id)
        {
            //As the repository uses IQueryable I used .ProjectTo
            //which I read was the best way to handle it.
            var fixture = fixtureRepository.GetFixtures().Where(c => c.vessel_idx == id)
                .ProjectTo<FixturesViewModel>();                    
            return Json(fixture);
        }
    }
}
```

**FixturesRepository**

Shortened for brevity

```
namespace DataAccessTest.DAL
{
    public class FixturesRepository : IFixturesRepository, IDisposable
    {
        private CoreEntities context;
        public FixturesRepository(CoreEntities context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }        
        public IQueryable<tbl_vessel_fixtures> GetFixtures()
        {
            return context.tbl_vessel_fixtures;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**IFixturesRepository**

```
namespace DataAccessTest.DAL
{
    public interface IFixturesRepository : IDisposable
    {
        IQueryable<tbl_vessel_fixtures> GetFixtures();
    }
}
```

**The KendoUI MVC Grid**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DataAccessTest.ViewModels.FixturesViewModel>()
    .Name("fixtures")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.vessel_idx)
            .Title("Vessel Id");
        columns.Bound(c => c.vessel_name)
            .Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(c => c.fixture_date)
            .Title("Date")
            .ClientTemplate("#=fixture_date ? kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(fixture_date), 'dd/MM/yyyy') : '' #");
        columns.Bound(c => c.charterer_company)
            .Title("Charterer");
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable(sort => sort.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
    .Groupable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("fixtures", "Grid", new { id = Model.vessel_idx }))
        .PageSize(10)
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add(a => a.fixture_date).Descending())
        ))
```

**Global.asax**

This is where I initilize the automapper configuration.

```
    // Automapper
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<FixturesViewModel, tbl_vessel_fixtures>().ReverseMap());
```

If I don't use automapper and create this mappings manually then it works fine, but if I attempt to use automapper it DOES get data but won't show it in the grid.  I'm not sure if my configuration is wrong or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your (browser) console showing any errors? Whenever my KendoUI controls break that's typically where I find out what's wrong.

Comment: I have just fixed it and I'm ashamed to say it was an easy fix.  Basically the grid was getting the data but not in a format that it understood, you need to use the .ToDataSourceResult() extension method.  I added a line to use that extension method and now it works.  Fully fleshed answer will follow once I can post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found a few additional details about this sort of issue (grid not returning data).  This isn't a problem with Automapper or the method itself, what I forgot to do was ustilise the extention method `.ToDataSourceResult`.  A little change to the method and I now have the data I am expected.

```
public ActionResult fixtures([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int id)
{
    var fixture = fixtureRepository
        .GetFixtures()
        .Where(c => c.vessel_idx == id)
        .ProjectTo<FixturesViewModel>();

    var result = fixture.ToDataSourceResult(request);

    return Json(result);
}
```